# Where can I find an assembler for the x86?

Tags: x86, assembly

I study ASM-86 language at high school and I want to program a little at home.

Do you know any "compiler" for this language that I can program and view the state of the memory?

Comment: It's called an "assembler".  Compilers are for higher-level languages like C.

Answer (score 4):

A compiler for an assembly language is commonly called "an assembler".

`MASM` and [`NASM`](http://www.nasm.us/) are two popular ones. Another pretty good option is writing [inline assembly in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93%28VS.80%29.aspx), thus benefiting from its great debugger.

Comment: I understand that NASM is an assembler,
and the program that I use to check the memory is radare?

And thanks for all the responses :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use nasm + radare + objdump

http://www.nasm.us/

http://radare.nopcode.org/new/

Answer (score 2):

Remember, he wants to view memory (and probably registers) too.

The gdb debugger is a real pain to work with assembler code.  (Don't get me wrong, I'm a fanboy).

The Insight debugger uses gdb for a back end, although the one time I tried to use it on a real program, I couldn't get it to work correctly.

The Open Watcom project has free tools and a windowed debugger.  You can use the included WASM assembler or NASM with the debug switch to allow viewing memory by label.

Answer (score 1):

If you are under Linux, the easiest choice is probably a combination of :

- [GNU As](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html)
- [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Both are included with your Linux system (or can be installed automatically by simply selecting them from the package manager). I personally prefer Unix systems for developing. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean for x86 assembly language then try:

I prefer [yasm](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/)
Supports 16, 32, and 64 bit coding and has fairly good macro support.

Also portable to different platforms unlike assemblers like [fasm](https://flatassembler.net/).